# regex match mathematical expression

Tags: regex, r

Can someone explain why this regex does not match `-+*\` in the center? I thought the expression `[+-\\*]{1}` would match a single operator, and reject strings like `222` which this regex accepts

```
expr<-c("1+2","222","")
res<-lapply(expr,function(x){regmatches(x,regexpr("[0-9]+[+-\\*]{1}[0-9]+", x,))})
```

GOAL:
1+2

Also, why can I not extend that pattern by using `([0-9]+[+-\\*]{1}[0-9]+){1,}` to match `1*2+2 and 1+8*2+2*4.....`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one thing you probably need to change `-` to `\-` (`\\-` in R) after the `+` because I don't think you meant to specify a character range.

Comment: `\-` is an unrecognized escape character in that regex

Comment: @Rilcon42 - See my edit to this answer. Single backslash needs to be escaped in R, so it's `\\-`